# Bell partial numbers

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, stirling-numbers, set-partition

Consider the problem of partitioning a set with $n$ elements into at most $k$ parts. Clearly, when $k\geq n$, the answer is $B_{n}$ (the $n$th [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number)).

What happens when $k<n$ (beyond that this is a partial sum of Stirling numbers of the second kind)? Do these numbers have a name (something like *incomplete* or *partial Bell numbers*)? Is there a good reference to this topic?

**Edit:** As discussed in the comments, this is the sequence [A102661](https://oeis.org/A102661) in the  [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/).

Comment: When you have a question about a combinatorial sequence, [oeis](https://oeis.org) should be about your first stop.  In this case, if you generate a list of the number of partitions of 10 for each k in 1..10, $1, 6, 14, 23, 30, 35, 38, 40, 41, 42$, oeis will point you to [A026820](https://oeis.org/A026820) which will answer your question in more detail than you could hope to get here.

Comment: @deinst: The sequence I need involves partitioning sets, not integers. The right sequence is [A102661](https://oeis.org/A102661). Anyway, your advice was extremely useful.

Comment: I apologize for not being careful  when reading your problem.  The mention of Bell numbers should have alerted me.  Anyway, I hope that oeis gave you more info than you neeeded.